# Appending a list within a for loop?

Tags: python, nested-lists

There are 2 given lists, suppose:

```
list1 = ['node1','node2','node3','node4']
list2 = ['goal1','goal2','goal3']
```

I require a list which returns:

```
result = [['node1','node2','node3','node4','goal1'],
       ['node1','node2','node3','node4','goal2'],
       ['node1','node2','node3','node4','goal3']]
```

Here is what I have:

```
result = []
for i in range (len(list2)):
    list1.append(list2[i])
    result.append(list1)
    list1.pop()
```

The problem is, result is not being appended with the desired value. It prints,

```
[['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4'],
 ['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4'],
 ['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4']]
```

after the `for` loop is completed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are running into this problem because your list `result` contains 3 copies of `list1`, not three separate lists. See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `list1` each goal to the end to list1 using a list comp:

```
list1 = ['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4']
list2 = ['goal1', 'goal2', 'goal3']
print([list1 + [gl] for gl in list2])
```

Output:

```
[['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', 'goal1'], 
['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', 'goal2'], 
['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', 'goal3']]
```

Comment: Definitely a better approach than any of the `append` or `extend` answers. You actually don't even need the slice with this version.

Comment: @user2357112, indeed,  each `list1 + [gl]` is creating a new list

Comment: +1 I didn't see this and posted a very similar answer. Definitely the best approach. List comprehensions rock!

Answer (score 4):

What your loop is doing is repeatedly appending the same list object (`list1`) to `result`. You can verify that by doing something like `list1.append(True)` after running the loop and checking `result` again:

```
[['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', True], 
 ['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', True], 
 ['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', True]]
```

What you want to do is instead [make a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/789671) of `list1` to append each time, such as:

```
for i in range (len(list2)):
    list1.append(list2[i])
    result.append(list(list1))
    list1.pop()
```

Although I would probably instead make use of list concatenation, which implicitly makes a new list:

```
for item in list2:
    result.append(list1 + [item])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this using `extend`:

```
>>> for i in range(len(list2)):
    tmp = []
    tmp.extend(list1)
    tmp.append(list2[i])
    all_paths.append(tmp)


>>> all_paths
[['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', 'goal1'], ['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', 'goal2'], ['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', 'goal3']]
```

Comment: Thank you! this works! But can you explain why was all_paths (now changed to "results" in the question) not storing desired lists in my code?